# Calculating a series approximation for pi & scheme syntax

Tags: syntax, scheme, racket, pi

Im taking a run with scheme for the first time & am trying write a simple recursive function which will calculate pi using the [Leibniz formula](https://wikimedia.org/api/rest_v1/media/math/render/svg/fab3e3e4febf987b57159d81fd47995fb0af1240). The procedure takes in the accuracy needed and returns an appropriate pi approximation.

for example: make-pi 0.001 -> 3.14109...

Im getting caught up with the syntax however and am a lost in the syntax and proper way to call/return variables in scheme.

```
; Define count for number of loops, sum for pi estimate, and num/denom for calculating estimation in series
(define count 1.0)
(define sum 4.0)
(define denomenator 3.0)
(define numerator 4.0)

; make-pi gets accuracy needed as input ie (make-pi 0.001 => 3.1410926536210413
(define make-pi
  (lambda (accuracy)
    ; determine if next fraction will be + or - based on number of iterations thus far
    (if (zero? sign count)
        ; add fraction if odd, subtract otherwise
        (+ sum (/ numerator denomenator))
        (- sum (/ numerator denomenator)))
    (define (check-accuracy sum)
      ; use check accuracy with current sum
      (if (zero? check-accuracy)
          ;return sum if within needed accuracy
          sum
          ; update count and new denom values if not accurate enough
          ; loop back if sum is not accurate enough
          (begin
            (+ count 1)
            (+ denomenator 2)
            (make-pi (sum)))))))



; if interation is even return 1 else 0
(define sign
  (lambda (count)
    (if (even? count))
  1
  0))

; if pi - sum is within desired accuracy, return 1 else 0
(define check-sum
  lambda (sum)
  (define check-accuracy
    lambda (accuracy)

  (if ((- 3.14159265358979 sum) < (abs(accuracy))))
  1
  0))
```

Comment: Racket actually formats the code for you press CTRL+i to reformat. What is your question?

Comment: @Sylwester Thanks, good to know. I am trying to correct syntax. For example using the sign procedure to give the correct fraction when going through the series. And ensuring I am defining variables correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How to call variables. Given that the symbol `add` evaluates to a procedure you call by enclosing them in parentheses:

```
(add 1 2) ; returns 3 if `add` is like global variable `+`
```

Basically it is the semantic eqvivalent to `add(1, 2)` in Algol languages. 
Be careful not to use extra parentheses since ((add 1 2)) is the same as `add(1, 2)()` etc.

How to return a variable. Well you let it be the tail expression.

```
(define (positive? n)
  (if (> 0 n)
      #t         ; tail that returns true 
      #f))       ; tail that returns false
```

Actually what happens is that `if` either does the consequent or the alternative based on the test. SO the result of the whole `if` form becomes either true or false and the `if` also returns that value. Ultimately the last expression of the procedure which happen to be the `if` expression gets returned as result of `positive?`.

You make a global variable with `define`

```
(define my-value 10) ; my-value is 10
```

And of course a procedure is a value:

```
(define add1 (lambda (n) (+ n 1))) ; value of add1 is a procedure
```

However `(define sign (count))` will create the variable `sign` to be the result of calling the procedure `count` with no arguments. `var sign = count();`. `(define check-accuracy lambda)` is the same as `var checkAccuracy = lambda;`, probably not bound.

`(((- 3.14159265358979 sum) < (abs(accuracy)))))` is the same as:
`sub( 3.14159265358979, sum)(some-variable-<, abs(accuracy()))()`

In Scheme you probably want `(< (- 3.14159265358979 sum) (abs accuracy))` instead.

A `define` (helper) inside a procedure needs to be at the beginning before the body of the procedure. eg.

```
(define (fibonacci n)
  ; define a local helper procedure
  (define (helper n a b)
    (if (zero? n)
        a
        (helper (- n 1) b (+ a b))))

  ; use the helper
  (helper n 0 1))
```

And since `(define (proc arg ...) body ...)` is the same as `(define proc (lambda (arg ...) body ...))` you can write the same:

```
(define fibonacci (lambda (n)
  ; define a local helper procedure
  (define helper (lambda (n a b)
    (if (zero? n)
        a
        (helper (- n 1) b (+ a b)))))

  ; use the helper
  (helper n 0 1)))
```

Helpers that does not use the free variables can be global. They are easier to test on their own that way. You can move them inside as helpers later (or not)

```
(sign 1) ; ==> is it 0?
```

Remember to take time to learn the language. This is probably the second time you learn a new language and would be different than learning a new dialect of a language you already know.

Answer (score 1):

One can also use 'named let' for recursion (see inline comments for description):

```
(define (myfn acc)
  (let loop ((sum 0)                           ; starting values
             (denom 1)
             (sign 1))
    (if (< (abs (- 3.14159265358979 sum))      ; check accuracy
           (abs acc))
        (exact->inexact sum)                   ; if accurate, end with output
        (loop (+ sum (* 4 sign (/ 1 denom)))   ; else loop again with next values
              (+ 2 denom)                     
              (if (= sign 1)-1 1)))))
```